# using location.pathname to add a class

Tags: jquery, css, url, jquery-selectors

I would like jQuery to pull the url, then parse it to find airports. If airports is found, I would like to add a class to the list-item `<a`> tag that contains the html "Airports".

This is what I have so far:

**JQuery**

```
path_name=location.pathname;

if ((path_name.search("airports")  > 0) {
        $("div.more li a").find(":contains('airports')").addClass("current-menu-item");
}
```

**The html looks like this:**

```
<ul>
  <a class="static" href="#">ALL</a>
  <li><a class="static" href="#">AIRPORTS</a></li>
</ul>
```

**URL is this:**

```
http://localhost/site/?type=airports
```

Is this a syntax problem or an "Try another way" problem?

UPDATE:

Using the alert suggestion, I was able to verify I am getting the url using location.search.
var search_name = location.search;
alert(search_name);

gave me the pop-up

```
?type=airports
```

So I am getting the correctly loaded variable, I just cannot write the logic to add the class. So far the suggestions are ont working.

**UPDATE 2**

This is working for an isolated incident.

```
var search_name = location.search;
    if (search_name.search("airports")  > 0) {
        alert(search_name);
        $("div.more a:contains('AIRPORTS')").addClass("active");
    }

});
```

I would like to make a bit more flexible by passing a variable.

How do you do thins? This is what I have so far

```
$(function() {
    var search_name = location.search;
    if (search_name.search("+ search_name +")  > 0) {
        alert(search_name);
        $("div.more a:contains('AIRPORTS')").addClass("active");
    }

    });
```

But this is not working.

Comment: try `search_name.search(search_name)` instead of `search_name.search("+ search_name +")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...with some minor corrections, this should work: http://jsfiddle.net/a4tWE/2/

- used location.href instead
- the :contains selector works case sensitive
- removed bracket

  if ((path_name.search("airports")  > 0) {
- removed find, as contains does the job.

Comment: Wouldn't I replace path_name.search("display") with path_name.search("+ search_name +")? I tried both with no luck.

Comment: 'display' was just an example, as it was in the jsfiddle url. you should change it .

Comment: This is throwing a syntax error for me. Not sure why because the fiddle looks fine. Thanks, this helped greatly

Answer (score 1):

`location.search` is the part containing airport. It is everything following `?` and is not included in `location.pathname`

Answer (score 1):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location): an example on getting value from search string.

```
function loadPageVar (sVar) {  
 return unescape(window.location.search.replace(new RegExp("^(?:.*[&\\?]" +      escape(sVar).replace(/[\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "(?:\\=([^&]*))?)?.*$", "i"), "$1"));  
}  

alert(loadPageVar("name"));
```

Comment: This is showing in the alert "The page at localhost says:" so it look slike it cannot pull the url correctly. Any chance this is because it is on localhost? Seems unlikely.

Comment: Not sure where you are getting "The page at localhost says" but window.location is url of the document so if url is http://localhost that is your location.